Las notas se guardan pero muestra una página de error 405 en nodejs
Estoy haciendo una aplicación poniendo en práctica los microservicios. Tengo un servicio para el login (funciona perfectamente) y otro que gestiona las notas guardadas. Además tengo un cliente en javascript vanilla que es el que se encarga de mostrar y añadir las notas. El problema está en que si inicio sesión (usando jwt) y trato de guardar una nota  me muestra la siguiente página.

Pero cuando regreso a la página de las notas me encuentro con que se guardan correctamente. No es un problema de CORS ya que la consola no lo indica.
Paso el código a continuación
Código del cliente
    document.getElementById("loginForm").addEventListener("submit", handleFormSubmit);
document.getElementById("registerForm").addEventListener("submit", handleFormRegister)
document.getElementById("notesForm").addEventListener("submit", handleNotesForm)
const username = document.getElementById("username");
const password = document.getElementById("password");

const notas = document.getElementById("note");
const noteForm = document.getElementById("notas")

async function handleFormRegister(e) {
  e.preventDefault()

  try {
    const registerData = await registerUser(username.value, password.value)


    const registro = document.createElement("h4")
    const registroMsg = document.createTextNode(registerData.result)

    noteForm.innerHTML = ``
    registro.appendChild(registroMsg)

    noteForm.appendChild(registro)
  } catch(error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}

async function handleFormSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  try {
    const loginData = await loginUser(username.value, password.value);
    const verificationResult = await verifyToken(loginData.token);


    localStorage.setItem("jwt", loginData.token)
    
    mostrarNotas(loginData.token)

  } catch (error) {
    const noteError = document.createElement("h3")
    const textError = document.createTextNode("Error al iniciar sesión")

    noteError.appendChild(textError)
    noteForm.appendChild(noteError)
  }

  username.value = ""
  password.value = ""
}

async function loginUser(username, password) {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/login", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ username, password })
  });

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error('Error en el inicio de sesión');
  }
  
  return await response.json();
}

async function verifyToken(token) {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/verifyToken", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ token })
  });

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error('Error verificando el token');
  }
  
  return await response.json();
}

async function getNotes(token) {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/notes", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  });

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("Error al obtener las notas");
  }

  return await response.json();
}

async function registerUser(username, password) {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/register", {
    method : "POST",
    headers : {
      "Content-Type" : "application/json"
    },
    body : JSON.stringify({ username, password })
  })

  if(!response.ok) {
    return await response.json()
  }

  return await response.json()
}


// FIXME Cuando se hace submit en el formulario de guardar notas sale un error 405
//        Las notas se guardan a pesar de mostrar el error
async function handleNotesForm() {

  const token = localStorage.getItem("jwt")
  const dataToken = await verifyToken(token)

  if(dataToken.valid) {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/notes", {
      method : "POST",
      headers : {
        "Content-Type" : "application/json",
        "Authorization" : `Bearer ${token}`
      },
      body : JSON.stringify({
        "user" : dataToken.username,
        "note" : notas.value
      })
    })
  } else {
    //TODO Implementar función que se ejecutará en caso de que el token no sea válido
    alert("No se ha podido guardar la nota, pruebe a iniciar sesión nuevamente")
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("jwt")

  if(token) {
    mostrarNotas(token)
  }

})

async function mostrarNotas(token) {
  const notes = await getNotes(token);

  noteForm.innerHTML = '';
  console.log(notes)
  if(notes.length === 0) {
    const noteElement = document.createElement("p")
    const text = document.createTextNode("No hay notas guardadas")

    noteElement.appendChild(text)

    noteForm.appendChild(noteElement)
  } else {
    notes.forEach(note => { 
      const noteElement = document.createElement("h2");
      const text = document.createTextNode(note.note);
      noteElement.appendChild(text);
      noteForm.appendChild(noteElement);

    });
  }
}

Y este es el código del servidor de notas
const express = require("express")
const axios = require("axios")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")

const router = express.Router()

router.use(bodyParser.json())
const notes = []
router.post("/notes", async (req, res) => {
  const token = getToken(req)
  
  let tokenValid = await isTokenValid(token)

  console.log(tokenValid)
  if(tokenValid.valid) {
    notes.push(req.body)

    res.status(201).send("Nota creada")
  } else {
    res.status(401).send("Token inválido")
  }
})

router.get("/notes", async (req, res) => {
  const token = getToken(req)
  const tokenValid = await isTokenValid(token)
  
  if(tokenValid.valid) {
    const userNotes = notes.filter(notes => notes.user === tokenValid.username)
    res.json(userNotes)
  } else {
    res.status(401).send("Token invalido")  }
})

const getToken = req => req.header("Authorization").replace("Bearer ", "")
const isTokenValid = async token => {

  try {
    const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/verifyToken", { token })
    const resValid = response.data


    return resValid
  } catch(error) {
    console.error(`Error en la verificación del token ${error.message}`)
    return { valid : false}
  }
}
module.exports = router

Y esta es la aplicación app.js del servidor
const express = require("express")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const cors = require("cors")
const routes = require("./routes/routes")

const PORT = 3001

const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())
app.use("/", routes)

app.listen(PORT, (req, res) => {
  console.log(`Servidor escuchando en el puerto ${PORT}`)
})


"No es un problema de CORS ya que la consola no lo indica." no, es un problema de que intentas leer un objeto null. Te lo pone exactamente en la consola...
